# ggplot2 library installed but not shown installed packages

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have installed ggplot2 package by using the command install.packages("ggplot2") in Rstudio. After checking in installed.packages(), i am not seeing any ggplot2 in installed packages as well(Searched with installed.packages()). 
[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me on this please ?

Comment: you are getting an error during install of `ggplot2` so it is not installing. When it asks if you would like to install the package from source, say no. Try `install.packages("ggplot2", type="binary")`. The error message also says you are missing the colorspace package so try `install.packages("colorspace")` first. What version of R are you running?

Comment: @MrFlick I am using R 3.4.4 Version.

Comment: Your R version is a bit out of date. These problems would probably go away if you update to a more recent version of R like R 3.6.2

Comment: @MrFlick I have installed colorspace package and then installed ggplot2 package by using the command ( install.packages("ggplot2")) without using type =  "binary". Now the package is shown in the installed packages list. Can you tell me what exactly happened. What is the significance of giving type = "binary"

Answer (score 0):

install.packages("ggplot2", type="binary") <- this works for me in R 3.6.2 version.it will shows warnings but not an error anymore.